# Lemma 6 in the proof of Schwartz's theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm reading Chapter 10 of [Sotomayor's book](https://es.b-ok.lat/book/19141406/224173) on Schwartz's theorem on flows on a compact two-dimensional surface, which follows the [original proof](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373135).

My first question is here: The following statement is found in either of the two links above. Letting $W$ be open in $(-1,1)$ and such that $G\subset W\subset \overline{W}\subset V$, we summarize te properties of $f$:

1. $G=(-1,1)-\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i,b_i)\subset W$
2. $f(G)=G$
3. $f^k(v)=v$ and $v\in G$ implies $k=0$
4. $G$ is minimal for $f$, in the following sense that $G$ does not contain any closed proper subset $K$ such that $f(K)=K.$

I manage to understand the test that is done in Sotomayor's book until before the red box, I just don't understand that very well. I know that there must exist a neighborhood $\tilde{V}$ of $\varphi(t_0,p)$ such that $\tilde{V}\cap\tilde{K_0}=\emptyset$. But I don't know how to get to that part of red. Just that part of red is what leads to a contradiction.

[image]

On the other hand, I also have problems understanding the proof of Lemma 6: There exists a interval $(a,b)$ such that $a<b;\;a,b\in G$ and $f^k((a, b))\subset W$ for all $k\geq 0$. Assuming that $f$ is monotone.

At one point in the demonstration they mention the following,
$$
s_0\in G-K_1\Leftrightarrow\text{ for all }\epsilon>0\text{ we have }\;G\cap (s_0-\epsilon,s_0)\neq\emptyset\wedge G\cap (s_0,s_0+\epsilon)\neq\emptyset
$$
I understand its use but I don't know how to get to test that if and only if mentioned above. Thanks to anyone who can help me understand this demo. Please be clear and if possible detailed to understand the essence of this demonstration.